# Change Date Format in OSX Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I am storing a Curl command output in a variable which comes as a date. (any previous date)

```
date=`curl ...`
```

The output is:

```
03-22-2021
```

Now I want to change this date format to below

```
March 22, 2021
```

I am running below commands:

```
currDate="03-22-2021"
formattedDate=`date -d "${currDate}" +%B %d, %Y`
echo $formattedDate
```

But I am getting this error

```
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

is it possible to use such a date format? How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my above question as per below for OSX

```
currDate="03-22-2021"
formattedDate=`date -jf "%m-%d-%Y" "${currDate}" +"%B %d, %Y"`
echo $formattedDate
```

Output is:-

```
March 22, 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to use such a date format?

No.

> How to do it?

Convert the format to something GNU date can eat. Then pass it.

I typically look at `man date`:

> DATE STRING
> The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29  16:21:42"  or  even
> "next Thursday". [...]

I recommend to use `YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss` format and add also timezone information.

```
tmp=03-22-2021
date -d "${tmp:6:4}-${tmp:0:2}-${tmp:3:2} 12:00:00 UTC" "+%B %d, %Y"
```

Do not use backticks ` . Use `$(..)` instead.

Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

The format argument to `date` has to be one argument, not `+%B %d, %Y` three.

For explanation of `${tmp:5:4}` expansion see variable expansion section in bash manual.

For anything more complicated with dates in shell, I recommend `dateutils` package with  `strptime` command.

> in OSX Command

On OSX install GNU date or install `dateutils`. The BSD date available on OSX is not capable of reading user input.